# Which software systems exist for creating Web pages from arbitrary database structure?

Tags: content-management-system, software-distribution

I would like to know whether there are software that a user can edit or create the database structure from WEB-UI, and after automatically generated CRUD pages.

WEB-Site can use not only personal with developer skills. Advanced users, managers also can use system functionality. As joomla, only with other features they are talking about above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[www.enterprise-elements.com](http://www.enterprise-elements.com)

To Elaborate: this system allows you to create simple or complex schemas, and then you get full CRUD functionality enabled in web pages, as well as a whole bunch of queries that get autogenerated.  A full security model is layered on, and the result is a CRUD complete system on your own schema in very little time.

The web page is directed at specific solutions, but this is the basic functionality of the tool.